# Query: How to obtain the most recent message per one user conversations?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a conversations table that is very simple but important (created_by is the code of the user who sent the message). Then, I have a conversations_messages table (sent_by is the code of the user who sent the message, message is my message text and created_at is the timestamp). Finally I have a conversations_users table that has the user_id (code of the user who received the message) and created_by (code of the user who sent the message).

I am trying to implement the functionality of inbox, I want to show the last message per conversation. user_id in conversations_users is the user who received the message and the user who is consulting his inbox.

I tried this query but I don't know how to deal with the created_at timestamp (in table conversations_messages) in order to get the most recent message per conversation.

```
select CM.id, CM.message, CM.created_at, C.id as 'conversation_id' from conversations_users CU 
    join conversations C on CU.conversation_id = C.id join conversations_messages CM on C.id = CM.conversation_id where CU.user_id = 1 and CM.created_at = '2015-03-10 14:18:02'
```

I have to replace '2015-03-10 14:18:02' for some most recent created_at timestamp thats my problem.

My tables are:

1. conversations_users: id, conversation_id, user_id, created_by
2. conversations: id, created_by
3. conversations_messages: id, conversation_id, sent_by, message, created_at

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM conversations_messages cm
JOIN conversations c ON cm.conversation_id = c.id
JOIN conversations_users cu ON cu.conversation_id = c.id
WHERE cu.user_id = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (    SELECT 'a'
                    FROM conversations_messages cm2
                    WHERE cm2.conversation_id = cm.conversation_id
                    AND cm2.created_at > cm.created_at
                    )
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach joining the table back to itself using the `max` aggregate, grouping by each conversation:

```
select CM.id, CM.message, CM.created_at, C.id as 'conversation_id' 
from conversations_users CU 
    join conversations C on CU.conversation_id = C.id 
    join conversations_messages CM on C.id = CM.conversation_id 
    join (
        select max(created_at) maxcreated_at, conversation_id 
        from conversations
        group by conversation_id 
    ) T on T.maxcreated_at = CM.created_at 
           and T.conversation_id = CM.conversation_id 
where CU.user_id = 1
```